# Academic writing Photo or Photograph

Tags: word-choice

Which one of these two forms would be more appropriate in academic writing.
The text does concern The Holocaust and is being translated from Polish into English.

This is **a photo** presenting bodies of the murdered ones laying on a Jewish cemetery."

This is **a photograph** presenting bodies of the murdered ones laying on a Jewish cemetery."

Oh I forgot shouldn't it be laying **in** a Jewish cemetery because **in** is the proper preopsition for cemetery ?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Whether *photo* is acceptable for *photograph* is a matter of preference, not of correctness; adhere to the guidance provided by your editor and the style guides of the publications you are submitting to. I am not an academic writer, but I can think of no place that would reject *photo*, even publications which are otherwise stylistically conservative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, *photo = photograph = picture produced by photography* and therefore, they're interchangeable, although *photo* is the short form and more commonly used in the spoken language.

Next, the verb in such a context is *to lie*, which means *to rest, to remain in the horizontal position*.

*lying in* would be more appropriate here. You're right, the preposition should be *in* and not *on*, because *cemetery* is a place.

The difference between *to lay* and *to lie* is better understood by the following examples:

They carefully laid the bodies down on the ground.
The bodies lie (or *are lying)* on the ground.

Comment: The choice of "on" might be deliberate by the author, even though slightly awkward.  Since bodies are *buried* **in** a cemetery, the author might be stressing the fact that the bodies are in fact **not** "in" the ground as "upon" the ground which suggests desecration.

Comment: Good point. Given that it's a translation from the source language, Polish, I believe that was part of the OP's question.

Comment: I would use "photograph" precisely because the short form feels more informal and it isn't part of a set phrase (e.g. "mobile phone"), but that's just me.

Comment: That's right. OP mentions "academic writing" and so it's a better option.

Comment: Given the context, photograph seems better, if only to help eliminate any casual tone.